# Restore anchor default event after event.preventDefault()

Tags: jquery, events, anchor, default, flexslider

So I'm using flexslider for my image slider. Long story short, I have added another list item to the end of the list of anchors that you click to go to a certain image in the slider. The list item I added needs to link to a page on the site. Instead of sending you to, for example google.com, it just breaks the image slider. I am fairly positive that this is due to the event.preventDefault() in the flexslider jquery. Is there a way to restore the event back to default for this particular link that I added?

Comment: nope. However, you can re-create the default action. `window.location = this.href`

Comment: Thank you very much. I believe that should be a simple solution.